# How to speed up display of modal in Angular app?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I'm making a web app with AngularJS and Angular Bootstrap. I am using a modal to allow the user to select one of many items in a list. The list is rendered with ng-repeat.

On some mobile platforms, there is quite a delay (3-5 seconds) between the user pressing the button that launches the modal and when the modal finally appears. I'm not sure whether the wait is caused by Angular rendering the DOM for that modal before the modal displays, or just by the sheer amount of content in the modal. It could be both. When I remove the ng-repeat list, the modal loads instantaneously.

I need to do one of the following:

(1) Cause Angular to build the DOM after the modal has displayed. It's not ideal, but at least the display of the modal would let the user know that their touch registered and something is happening.

(2) Cause the modal to display more quickly despite the large amount of content.

Any thoughts on how to make either of those happen?

Comment: How much data is shown by the ng-repeat? (How many iterations, how many "colums"/"fields" for each item?)

Comment: there's a 300ms delay on mobile devices touch actions: http://www.sitepoint.com/5-ways-prevent-300ms-click-delay-mobile-devices/

Comment: @StephenFriedrich There are a few hundred repeats. Also, the list has a couple of filters. When I removed the ng-repeat, the modal opened almost instantaneously.

Comment: @NitsanBaleli Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, the delay I am experiencing is much more than 300 ms. My iPhone is taking several seconds to display a modal that displays in less than a second on Android and on desktop.

Comment: I am afraid in that case you have hit a hard performance limit in angular on the iphone. There are a couple of tricks to get better performance. For example you could have the user paginate through the results in chunks of 100 items - that would keep the dom smaller and probably help. For large datasets I sometimes reverted to using lodash templates, but that should really be a last resort. If you aren't on the lates 1.3 version, you could try that because there have been quite some performance improvements in angular.

Answer (score 0):

The modal instance has a property `rendered` which is a promise that is resolved when a modal is rendered. You may delay assigning large dataset to the modal scope until that promise is resolved.

```
$uibModal.open({
    controller: function ($uibModalInstance, $scope, data) {
        $uibModalInstance.rendered.then(function () {
            $scope.data = data;
        });
    },
    ...
});
```

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

But in my opinion, modals should not be used for large content blocks.